# Inscribing an equilateral triangle ABC into another equilateral triangle XYZ with AB $\perp$ YZ

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Equilateral $\Delta ABC$ is inscribed in equilateral $\Delta XYZ$ with $AB \perp YZ$. What is the ratio of the area of $\Delta ABC$ to the area of $\Delta XYZ$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

The three external triangles are clearly congruent $1:\sqrt3:2$ right triangles, so the sides of the two equilateral triangles are in the ratio $\sqrt3:(2+1)=\sqrt3:3$. Therefore, the ratio of the two areas is $3:9 = 1:3$.

Answer (score 2):

Observe  that $AB=YB\tan \pi/3=\sqrt{3}AY$. On the other hand, $AC=AZ\sin \pi/3=\sqrt{3}AZ/2$ or $2AC=AZ\sqrt{3}$. Since $AB=AC$ when we add the previous equalities we get
$$
3AB=\sqrt{3}(AY+AZ)=\sqrt{3}YZ,\qquad AB=\sqrt{3}(AY+AZ)/3=\sqrt{3}YZ/3
$$
The ratio of the areas is the square of the ratio of the sides, that is
$$
Area(ABC)=\frac{1}{3}Area(XYZ).
$$